# akka http: docker container is not connecting to the server

Tags: scala, docker, akka-http

i have an akka htpp app here is how i am binding it

```
val host = "0.0.0.0"
    val port = 8080

    val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(MainRouter.routes, host, port)
log.info("Server online ")
    StdIn.readLine()
    bindingFuture
      .flatMap(_.unbind()) // trigger unbinding from the port
      .onComplete(_ => system.terminate()) // and shutdown when done
```

i am using [sbt native packager](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html#custom-dockerfile) to create my app docker image

i have also added

```
dockerExposedPorts:= Seq(8080)
```

in my `build.sbt`

i am running my container as
`docker run -p 8080:8080 testapp:0.0.1 --bind 0.0.0.0`

`docker ps` shows

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
2e8e7ae35b10        testapp:0.0.1     "/opt/docker/bin/tes…"   13 minutes ago      Up 13 minutes       0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   recursing_hellman
```

when i hit 0.0.0.0:8080 from browser i got

```
This site can’t be reached The connection was reset.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

or from `postman`

```
Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to 0.0.0.0:8080/event-id?id=132
```

while docker container is running on my machine
nc -zv 0.0.0.0 8080
returns

```
Connection to 0.0.0.0 8080 port [tcp/http-alt] succeeded!
```

inside the container

```
docker exec -it 2e8e7ae35b10 bash
```

i have tried

```
curl 'http://0.0.0.0:8080/health'
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 8080: Connection refused
```

my app works fine outside of docker

Comment: Could you check if there is any exception or error messages was thrown inside app, please? You can use `docker logs` for this purpose

Comment: there is no exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is thst docker closes standard input by default which may impact your app due to it's prompt about user input `StdIn.readLine()`. The solution could be to [run the container with the `-i` option to keep stdin open](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#foreground).

Let me know if it helps!!